# Organic groups - The OG groups of the logged in user

Tags: views, organic-groups

I need to list all users from organic groups in which the current (logged in) user is an administrator member.

I manage to list all users from groups where current user is member (using relationship - OG membership: OG membership from User and contextual filter - The OG groups of the logged in user), but I can not manage to get only groups where the current user has administrator privileges.

Some idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a contextual filter in views and add a Relation to the OG Roles.

1. Click on the advanced section in your view.
2. Add the contextual filter "Content: Groups audience (og_group_ref)"
3. Then select "Provide default value"
4. Choose "The OG groups of the logged in user" in the dropdown field
5. Add a relation "OG Roles from membership"
6. Add a filter "OG Role name" and choose the role you want to have

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that it's not working. I should be able to list the users from that groups. Do you have any idea?